# Changing from Android 2.2 to 2.1

Tags: android

I have developed an app using android 2.2, I want to downgrade it to 2.1 (to do some testing), 
Is this possible? If so how do I do this?

Comment: Change the android build target to api-7. Thats all you need. It can be easily done in eclipse in the project properties.

Comment: I am getting a lot of errors when I changed it..may be some methods aren't compatible with api-7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the project > BuildPath > configureBuildPath it will open properties box of project select android in left side box, and change the version

Comment: I am getting errors regrading <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Answer (score 2):

Well on most handsets you can only the version supplied by your vendor. But the android emulators can be used with all versions you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [list](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) that lines up the API number with the version of android.

As mentioend above (Someone beat me to the steps) the best thing to do is simply change that one number in eclipse, and wa-la you will be targeting that specific version.